# Ticketing system for a small company

Tags: work-place

I work for a small half-technological company. We want to implement a ticketing system so we can better track bugs. We don't have many of them, but we do have some customers now, so the tracking becomes problematic. 
So far we've used Trello.

I'm thinking about either Help Scout or Happy Fox, but do you have other recommendations?

Comment: This is very much an opinion-based question - please edit it so that instead of asking for recommendations you ask for pros and cons of different tools.

Answer (score 2):

What are your requirements?

I recommend Jira.  High quality software that is easy to use.  I like it because it is incredibly easy to integrate with other services like Jenkins, CircleCI, github, etc.  Also Atlassian (the maker) has a suite of tools that integrate well and will be useful to you if/when you grow bigger.

I've also used Pivotal Tracker, Trello and VSTS.  Jira is my clear favorite.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the list of ticket tracking tools which we are using, please check below for more details.

- [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/home)
- [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for any paid ticketing tool then go for [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira), [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/home), [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/). I prefer to use **Jira.**

If you are looking for any free tools then go to [Trello](https://trello.com/), [QATouch](https://www.qatouch.com/), [Bugzilla](https://www.bugzilla.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for open source then best choice is Mantis Bug Tracker, it is a free and open source, web-based bug tracking system. The most common use of MantisBT is to track software defects. However, MantisBT is often configured by users to serve as a more generic issue tracking system and project management tool.

- you can host the bugtracker on free hosting sites easily